# Как добавить кнопку в title bar

Tags: android

есть активити наследованный от mainactivity, у mainactivity в титле кнопка поиска, как в дочернем убрать эту кнопку и поставить другую и повесить на нее click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Toolbar меню]
Все кнопки действий и другие элементы, определяются в ресурсе меню XML. Чтобы добавить действия в панель действий, создайте новый файл XML в каталоге res / menu /.

Добавьте элемент  для каждого элемента, который вы хотите включить в панель действий, как показано в этом примере кода XML-файла меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
    android:title="@string/action_favorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Далее добавляем в код активити для обработки следующее:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:

            return true;

        case R.id.action_favorite:

            return true;

        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли об `setHasOptionsMenu(boolean hasMenu)`.